# How to restore nuget packages when those packages' version are superior to the runtime's version?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I've cloned this solution from **Azure DevOps**. And according to my coworker, it's working fine in the cloud. When I open it using Visual studio 2019, it's not restoring all the nugget packages. The project is targeting **netcore 2.1**, when I change the target to **netcore 2.2**, it restores, build, and run.

Here's the project:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

//...

<ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.2.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices" Version="2.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.0" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.2.0-preview1-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

As one can see here, the target is **2.1** while many of the packages are 2.2.0 or above.

My question is to know whether there's another way of making this project on local besides targeting **2.2** framework?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can open nuget manager and change package versions 2.1 or the way you want. Or you can change `csproj` like

```
ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

I think this is to risky because some method contents, names, parameters etc.. may have changed or new features may be included in version 2.2 of packages and they don't work for 2.1 versions.

Comment: Enes Bicer, I'm a little confused.  Do you mean that when the target is **2.1**, no package should be > to **2.1**? So far, when I change the `Target Framework` to **2.2**, it works because 2.2 is > or = 2.1. My question is to know whether there is a way to keep the Framework to 2.1 but with some package being of 2.2.

Comment: Yes if the target is 2.1 ,packages have to be =< 2.1 . There is no way to keep the Framework to 2.1 but with some package being of 2.2. Why you need to keep `Target  Framework` to 2.1 ? Why don't you want to use `.net core  2.2` version ?

Comment: I was just being curious. Thanks